# Как вернуться в начало цикла Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, while

Каким образом, при введении длины строки, не попадающей под условие,
вернуть цикл в самое начало?

***main.py***:

```py
while len(card) != 8:
    if len(card) == 8:
        print('Карта найдена.')
    else:
        print('Номер указан неверно. Попробуйте еще раз')
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
while True:
    card = input("Введите номер: ")
    if len(card) == 8:
        print('Карта найдена.')
        break
    else:
        print('Номер указан неверно. Попробуйте еще раз')
```

Comment: Сработало. Спасибо